# Using modified CC BY-SA 4.0 images in app?

Tags: creative-commons, attribution, cc-by-sa

I am building an application and I want to use OpenMoji in it, but with modified colors.

Firstly, I wanted to add

> All emojis designed by OpenMoji – the open-source emoji and icon
>   project. License: CC BY-SA 4.0

into the "About" section. But I read the license and it says that

> If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

So looks like OpenMoji with modified color are also CC BY-SA 4.0 licensed. Does it mean I need to provide a download link for recolored OpenMoji in my application?

What should I do according to this license in my situation?

Answer (score 1):

*If* you distribute in any way. Just showing them on your website is (arguably) not "distributing". In any case, you could place the modified icons/emoji somewhere a user can get them, with the respective notices (taken from so-and-so, modified by you, under CC-BY-SA) and link from e.g. the "About" or such page of your site.

Comment: Slightly different context, yet probably applicable : Displaying images on websites has been judged distribution and damages awarded to the rights holder - at least in Germany

Answer (score 1):

As the OpenMoji project is under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 license, you have the right to adapt the emojis by changing their color under these conditions

- Your adapted emojis must be under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 license or a later version
- You must give attribution to the OpenMoji project with an indication that you modified the emojis. As indicated in [their documentation](https://github.com/hfg-gmuend/openmoji#attribution-requirements), this attribution should include a link to the OpenMoji project.

You are **not** required to provide a download link for your modified emojis. For license compliance, it is enough that you don't forbid further modification if someone has scraped your modified emoji from your application.