# Do I have to open source my app if I use unmodified API data licensed under CC-BY-SA 4.0

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-notice, license, cc-by-sa

I'm working on a little Quiz App. To get questions I use [Open Trivia DB](https://opentdb.com/)

> All data provided by the API is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.

I have read a little bit about the license but I'm not sure if my app is an adaption of the work and therefor I have to publish it under CC-BY-SA 4 as well.

The app queries a question from the database, shows it to the user, and lets him chose an answer. It doesn't modify the question.

Follow up:

According to an answer to [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/using-modified-cc-by-sa-4-0-images-in-app) question.

> You are not required to provide a download link for your modified emojis. For license compliance, it is enough that you don't forbid further modification if someone has scraped your modified emoji from your application.

Does this mean if I have to make the app CC-BY-SA, I don't need to publish the source, and if so, how do I mark the app as CC-BY-SA in this case?

Comment: Do you include the corpus of questions in your distributed app, or do you pull it from the Internet at install time or question-asking time? If you don't distribute the data yourself, there's no way SA requirements apply to your application. If you do include them in what you distribute, there's a *possibility*, but also unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if the data is part of the code the copyleft **may** apply. But that is rather a gray area because including the data would not necessarily imply a derivative work. Better ask the original author and/or a lawyer :D

If you just pull the data in runtime, you are perfectly fine with any license otherwise possible. That's what CC is for!

Remember that you will have to comply to the "BY" in both cases.